# How to apply style for all vertices of MultiPolygon

Tags: openlayers

I use this obejct style for multi polygon type:

```
MultiPolygon: [
    new Style({
      stroke: new Stroke({
        color: blue,
        width,
      }),
      fill: new Fill({
        color: whiteOpacity,
      }),
    }),
    new Style({
      image: new Circle({
        radius,
        fill: new Fill({
          color: blue,
        }),
      }),
      geometry: (feature) => {
        const coordinates = (
          feature.getGeometry() as any
        ).getCoordinates()[0][0];
        return new MultiPolygon(coordinates);
      },
    }),
]
```

But only first polygon is styled -- how can I style all vertices of a multipolygon?

Comment: Your title and Question ask different questions. Do you want to style all vertices or all features? Please [Edit] the Question

Comment: Yes, I want to style all vertexes of multipolygon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to flatten the MultiPolygon coordinates to a depth of 2 to get the vertices for a MultiPoint geometry

```
MultiPolygon: [
    new Style({
      stroke: new Stroke({
        color: blue,
        width,
      }),
      fill: new Fill({
        color: whiteOpacity,
      }),
    }),
    new Style({
      image: new Circle({
        radius,
        fill: new Fill({
          color: blue,
        }),
      }),
      geometry: (feature) => {
        const coordinates = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates().flat(2);
        return new MultiPoint(coordinates);
      },
    }),
],
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/geojson-forked-4eid6f?file=/main.js